# Docker: Why does my home directory disappear after the build?

Tags: docker, directory, dockerfile

I have a simple docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER T-vK

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash -g dialout esp

USER esp 

WORKDIR /home/esp

COPY ./entrypoint_script.sh ./entrypoint_script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/esp/entrypoint_script.sh"]
```

when I run `docker build .` followed by `docker run -t -i ubuntu` and look for the directory `/home/esp` it is not there! The whole directory including it's files seem to be gone.
Though, when I add `RUN mkdir /home/esp` to my docker file, it won't build telling me `mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/esp': File exists`.

So what am I misunderstanding here?

I tested this on Debian 8 x64 and Ubuntu 16.04 x64.
With Docker version 1.12.2

Comment: Well, if you are starting it with `docker run -t -i ubuntu` then you aren't starting the container based on the image you just made, you are starting a container from the vanilla ubuntu image. Have you running the image you made?

Comment: I see. That makes sense now. I'll give it a try and get back.

Comment: Just in case you need it, the official docker docs on [building/tagging](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/) images are pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change you Docker build command to:

```
docker build -t my-docker:dev .
```

And then to execute:

```
docker run -it my-docker:dev
```

Then you'll get what you want. you didn't tag docker build so you're actually running Ubuntu image.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to tag an image to run it `docker run <image sha>` would work just as well as using a tag.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why I get a  "permission denied" error on my entrypoint now?

Comment: Is it executable? run `chmod +x entrypoint_script.sh` and test again.

Comment: btw, it's better to also change the owner of the file because COPY is always gives root permission to files. Add this to your Dockerfile after copy `RUN chown esp entrypoint_script.sh`

Comment: @R0MANARMY Of course you can, but I'd rather use proper tag than `<none> <none>` and weird uuids ! Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah, you'll generally want to tag your images, it just wasn't the issue Forivin was running into.